# Have only part of php document load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I have created a PHP/HTML document which uses jQuery to create a sliding page effect. I would like to have what the user selected on the first page correspond to what they see on the second page. I know how to do this if I was to use two separate pages however I would like to keep the sliding page effect.

The problem is that PHP is loaded first so for the second page nothing is displayed because on initially loading the page nothing is selected on the first page.
The only solution I have is to have the second page only load when the first is completed, but I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone know if its possible to have the document load at separate times?

**UPDATE**

On second thoughts could I use a XMLHttpRequest to achieve this? And if so how can I do this

Comment: Have the second page via ajax

Comment: @JohnConde I have tried using ajax to set the selected values in the HTTP POST but because the PHP is loaded first nothing is currently set in the POST until the javascript is run.